# Android studio download maven metadata every time during build

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, build.gradle

Every time I build my project android studio build system download '**maven-metadata.xml**'. As a result, it takes a very long time to build the project. Can anyone suggest me is there any way to fix this? Below is the picture of the problem.

[image]

Comment: Check your settings.xml and see what is the value for updatePolicy tag under repositories. The valid values are: always, daily (default), interval:X (where X is an integer in minutes) or never.

Comment: @rootkonda Would please tell me actually where settings.xm is located in android studio ?

Comment: it is a maven so not specific to android studio. The Maven installation directory: $M2_HOME/conf/settings. xml [global settings] or 
The user's home directory: ${user. home}/. m2/settings. xml [user settings]

Comment: thanks for the info. I'm checking it.

Comment: @FozleRabbiShafi Have you found the solution. Please share.

Comment: @mukesh Not till now. I am not working on android for a few days. If I find, I will definitely share it.

Comment: Switch Charles Proxy off.

Comment: is there any update about this issue?

Comment: Check your Maven repository definitions and check if they're working properly (they're accessible). If you have an invalid URL then Gradle will make a network call for each dependency you have while trying to resolve them, and it will do this in each configuration phase because it couldn't get the definitions previously.

Answer (score 8):

In Gradle Tool window (View -> Tool Windows -> Gradle), activate Toggle Offline Mode.
[image: Gradle toggle offline mode.]